# Unable to close window in XCode while i am pulling code from bitbucket

Tags: xcode, macos, bitbucket

How to gt rid of it? I tried to pull code from bitbucket but it shows like this.

Help me to close this. I am unable to scroll down and i don't want to quit it rather I want to close it(I need reason why it is not showing close option at top).

[image]

I am new to MAC, XCode, Bitbucket and stackoverflow too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a MAC OS issue. First try to hit "enter" and if the button in the popup is highlighted it will close it. If its not, there is no way to close it unless you connect a higher resolution screen so you can see the button.